# Tableau Using Parameters for a Date Selector

Tags: date, parameters, selector, tableau-api

I've been looking into making a date selector so instead of filtering by Month, Week by adding filters then displaying the quick filters to correspond. I want to be able to dynamically change the date so I can choose between Quarter, Month and Week in a single drop down.

I have made the selector part no problem it shows but when I come to my calculated field, it's not behaving how I would like.

Here is my calculated field:

```
CASE [Parameters].[Date Select]
WHEN 'Quarter' THEN  QUARTER([Date])
WHEN 'Month' THEN  MONTH([Date])
WHEN 'Week' THEN  WEEK([Date])
END
```

This gives 2 errors...

```
Unknown Function QUARTER called
Unknown Function WEEK called
```

I am puzzled because the month one is fine.

Normally in tableau to get the month/quarter/week, I click on the `Date dimension` and select Month or week and it filters and displays like so: `MONTH(Date)`.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong and how I can pull the week and quarter from date in the calculated field so my selector will work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no *QUARTER* and *WEEK* functions in Tableau, as you can see in the image below.
What you should be using to get these values are:

```
DATEPART('quarter',[Date])
DATEPART('week',[Date])
```

[image: Possible date formulas]

For filtering the date using your parameter as filter, I'll assume that you want to filter the **current** quarter, month or week. In this case you'll need to setup your paramaters like this:

[image: Date parameters]

Then you'll create a *Calculated Field* with the following formula:

```
DATEPART([Date Selector],[Date]) = DATEPART([Date Selector],TODAY())
```

This should give you a True/False dimension which you will use as filter for the value **True**. After that you should have a working parameter filtering your data accordingly to the value set.

Comment: Thanks so much, this gets rid of the errors. It doesn't change the data when I select  quarter month or year though.

Comment: I'll try to give you a complete answer to also solving your first problem. Let me try to understand what you need: you're trying to use parameters to filter the current quarter, month or week, right?